# ASP.NET MVC Webgrid column with actionlink, using lambda expression to get string for actionlink title?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, webgrid

Essentially I have a webgrid column and I want to populate it with actionlinks. The title of the actionlink needs to be dynamic and grabbed from a lambda expression. What I have is this:

```
grid.Column("Title", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("LAMDA", "Post", new { id = item.PostId }) </text>),
```

But what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
grid.Column("Title", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink((item) => (item).Title.ToString(), "Post", new { id = item.PostId }) </text>),
```

But this gives me error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.. for some reason you cannot use ToString(), I had to cast like (string)... weird

solution:

```
grid.Column(columnName: "Title", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.Title), "Post", new { id = item.PostId })),
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually written a Linq query - you've just passed in a Lambda function.  You'll need to do a whole query.  Also bear in mind that the query will likely return an IQueryable or IEnumerable so you'll probably need to call .Single or .First or similar on it to get a single string out.

Comment: And that query should be done in the Controller and returned as the model for the view, or added to the ViewBag

Comment: changed question to reflect lamda function instead of linq query. figured out answer below, very quirky... but thank you!